# Spring Data MongoDB Aggregation conversion?

Tags: java, mongodb, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb

I couldn't convert below mongodb aggregate operation to Spring Data AggregationOperation. I am using Spring Data MongoDB 1.3.2 version.

```
db.ads.aggregate( { $group :{ 
 _id : "$adId",
 req : { $sum : 1 }, 
 imp: {$sum: { $cond: [ { $eq: [ "$imped", true ] } , 1, 0 ] } },
 click: {$sum: { $cond: [ { $eq: [ "$clked", true ] } , 1, 0 ] } } ,
 bid: {$sum: { $cond: [ { $eq: [ "$clked", true ] } , "$bid", 0 ] } } } });
```

I stopped here:

```
AggregationOperation group = Aggregation.group("adId").count().as("req").sum("imped").as("imp").;;
```

I would appreciate any help, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Currently there is no support to have $cmp/$eq/$ne to be used in group
>   or project aggregation. It would be a good to have feature. Also it
>   would be helpful to improve on some of the documentation/examples for
>   Criteria features.

please let's vote in here: https://jira.springsource.org/browse/DATAMONGO-784